# How can I create a complex curve?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I need to create a curve based on this reference (only a 3D tube/line), but it seems hard to make it exact. Is there a way I can make it exactly look like the one in the image?

[image]

Comment: I would start with add>curves>extra objects>spirals (if you don't know how to enable extras, see this [post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9224/creating-clock-cogs/9226#9226)

Comment: Thank you, but it looks like a circle, can i put the spiral like a single line, like the picture that i posted? its the first time i use this option so i don't know :(

Comment: Increase the height parameters in the tool bar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a Path (*Add*-->*Curve*-->*Path*). Enter *Edit Mode*, select the curve with <kbd>A</kbd> and subdivide it as many times as you like (<kbd>W</kbd>).
Now select every third point of the curve.
[image]

Grab the points up.
[image]

You may notice, that the curve is not even in some places, so correct it.
[image]

Snap the cursor to the end of the curve, enable ***Proportional Editing*** and set the *Falloff Type* to ***Sphere***.
[image]

Scale it horizontaly, setting the *proportional size* to a proper value (use a mouse scroll).
[image]

Here is the final result.
[image]

Comment: Darn it, beat me to it XD

Comment: Wait, i could do this, because seems perfect to me, but i already had a curve, and it looks like this:https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/10455111_330438213811458_3595888784125957793_n.jpg?oh=cc00934c3e0f9f29d414e68621ba2b80&oe=553118F5&__gda__=1429068412_2593a75062e953bd84ce1b5d4d609c2e
As i see now the only problem that i got is the distance between the vertices, can i apply your method to my already made curve?

Comment: You should be able to.

Comment: I'm already doing this method, and it's working fine :)

Comment: Great to hear that mate :).